# How to resolve Missing descriptor for entity class in java

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle, eclipselink

I am working on the cloud migration for my application. As part of this the on premise DB oracle has been migrated to postgresql in AWS. After migration my java code is breaking in the following CursoredStream which was working before. I am using eclipselink version 2.5.2 and the java version is 17.

```
           Query activity_query = em.createNativeQuery(query.toString(), ActivityLog.class);
           claim_query.setHint("eclipselink.read-only", true);         
           claim_query.setHint("eclipselink.cursor", true);
           CursoredStream scrollableCursor = (CursoredStream) activity_query.getSingleResult();
```

The query is executing fine in pgadmin and there are a total of 130 columns being returned. I have validated all the table column names with the column names declared in the ActivityLog entity class with @Column annotation and also verified the return datatype for all the columns. Everything is looking good. The ActivityLog entity class is declared in the persistence.xml file as well. Tried upgrading the eclipse link version in pom.xml. But nothing seems to be working. After printing the stacktrace I am getting the below exception in the logs

```
           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:547)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
       at com.theapplication.detail.dao.AgedoutOfBalanceClaimsDAO.getReportOOBDataexcel(ActivityDAO.java:153)
       at com.theapplication.detail.service.AgedoutOfBalanceClaimsReportService.buildFile(ActivityService.java:152)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class com.theapplication.detail.entity.ActivityLog].
```

I tried out different solution available online and its still showing as Missing descriptor for [class com.theapplication.detail.entity.ActivityLog]. I am not able to post all the entity class code due to my organization policy. Stuck with this issue for more than 3 days now. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.